# Sharing a Google Doc you have created by putting it into a folder shared with you

Tags: google-drive

A folder with a bunch of work was shared with me. Call it "CSC". I made a spreadsheet, call it "hours".

How do I put the "hours" document into the "CSC" folder and make it shared with everyone else?

Comment: You can always copy-paste the spreadsheet to the CSC folder... even drag-and-drop works.

Comment: Now how would you drag and drop it? To get the file I go to "My drive" and the shared folder is under "Shared with me" so it's two completely different screens.

Comment: I thought you had downloaded Google Drive for PC. That will sync your local folders with the drive...
Otherwise..see the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the Shared collection/folder to your "My Drive." This can be done in the browser.

1. Go to your Drive and click on "Shared with me." You should see CSC there as usual
2. Select CSC by checking the box next to its name
3. At the top, click on Add to My Drive

This will make CSC show up in your "My Drive" list of documents while preserving the shared nature of the actual folder. You can now drag or move any other documents in "My Drive" into the folder, and it will be reflected for all users who share that folder.

**REMEMBER:** Any document from "My Drive" that you put into the Shared folder will inherit the level of access for the recipient. Meaning if you have a private doc that is put into the Shared folder, everyone who is included in the Shared folder will have access to this doc (view/edit based on their folder access).

Comment: Thanks man! One more glitch to work out. When I was trying to figure out how this works I created a new folder called log and put the file I wanted to share inside it. I now have shared the entire folder by putting it in CSC but how do you copy the spread sheet out so it's just in the base CSC folder and not it's own folder?

Comment: This is where @Kevan's advice comes in handy as well. You can go to the file you need to move, select it and then click on the "Organize" button that appears. This will allow you to move the file to another folder. Just select the new folder and hit "Apply changes"

Answer (score 0):

You can download the spreadsheet to your local machine (Select the filename, click on 'More' and then click on 'download...').

Then upload it to the CSC folder. (Go to the shared drive, Click on the red button next to 'Create...', it will ask for the file to be uploaded.)

Yes, this looks like a dirty trick... which it is.

If you are working a lot with Google drive, you can click on Offline Docs on the left panel. It will allow you to edit Google Docs on your local machine and then update changes to the shared file.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps to share a Google Doc with a Shared Folder

1. Use the Organize button at the top of your Docs list, it looks like a folder shape in Chrome, hover over it to see the name.
   Note: this button will only appear once you have selected (check box) the file(s) from the docs list you want to organize into "folders".
   Once you have the Organize window open you may have to expand the "Folders shared with me" section to find the destination folder(s).  Instructions will appear here if you have no folders listed in this area yet.
2. Check the Box to the left of the folder to "move" the file(s).  Use CTRL-Check to select multiple folder locations (I suggest leaving it in My Drive if you use it a lot)

Note that you can use CTRL-Click to add file(s) to multiple folders without removing from the original location.  This option lets you keep file(s) in multiple folders if you want.

Remember:  Once a file is shared with any folder all users of that folder will have access no matter what the Share settings IN the file say.